# Align HTML Text in a Div through CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
#homeButtonText{
font-size: 25px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Here's how it looks: 
[image]

How do I get the text on the inside to be right in the center.

I have tried,

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

with no success. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look, I've opened Goog and entered: `center text inside a div :stackoverflow` and there it is. Search before asking. Closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you set height to your div? You can use `line-height`
Check this here: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hLn4va8f/)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

FIRST - QUICKEST:

set `line-height:(button height)` to the `#homeButtonText`

SECOND - RECOMMENDED

use padding, like this:

```
padding:10px 20px;
```

so the text will be in center and you will have full control

Comment: padding is by far the best solution. line-height in my experience is really inaccurate or even misinterpreted across browsers & devices. Though using padding on an inline element you might want to set it to `inline-block` first

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`

```css
.button {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"><a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried positioning the text absolutely inside the div?

Something like:

```
top:50%;
left:50%;
```

Comment: `Top` should be `top`, `Left` should be `left` , your'e missing `;` , and position absolute with those parameters will really not lead to the needed result.

Comment: ah okay, I was just riffing off the top of my head. What's the main issue with it? Assuming proper syntax?

Comment: you cannot position *text* absolutely, just an element containing text. IF that's the case, create on your own a demo with your exact code and you'll see the issue.

Comment: Ah I see. I was just assuming a <p> or something. Thanks.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qixupi/1/edit

Comment: I dunno what I'm smoking then haha. Though if I had some I'd still share :)